# Software load balancer for Windows

Tags: windows, networking, load-balancing

I'm looking for a simple load balancing solution for Windows.

I have two machines (say host0 and host1), any of them is hosting TCP service (so it can be either host0 or host1, but never host0 and host1 together).

host0 has a client to that service. Could you please suggest me for the following load balancing scenario: once client initiates connection, load balancer tries to connect to both host0 and host1 services. Once one of host replies it routes all traffic to that host.

Update 0:

One of the possible solutions I'm looking at is writing a script on the client machine which finds out which host is running the service and updates HOSTS file. I don't like this approach too much as it is not fast enough. So any suggestions are very appreciated.

Update 1:

Looks like I can write a script which will run netsh interface portproxy to set up port forwarding. Looks like it is a better solution than HOSTS file. Does it make sense?

Thanks

Comment: If the service is running only on one of the hosts, then it's a **cluster**, not a load balancing. Load balancing is when the service is running on *both* hosts and they share the load.

Comment: Massimo, you are right. The only problem is that service is a GUI Java application so I can't host it with MSCS since I need to see its GUI on desktop and interact with it. Or I can?

Comment: If the service really is a GUI Java application, clustering it will be the least of your problems. What if you log off? Or if you are not available to log back on if/when the server reboots?

Comment: Log off issue is something I'm ready to deal with, I have an offshore team who monitors it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your service really shouldn't be a GUI application. Period.

Anyway, one solution that *could* work in this scenario if your application is able to listen on more than one IP address is giving the "active" server a second address and having your clients connect to that. To fail over, you will move the IP address to the other server and launch the application there.

This could also be automated using a failover cluster with a single IP address as a clustered resource, or a NLB cluster configured to only handle traffic for your application's TCP port (and to only send it to the host where that port is actually open); but I don't know how useful could a failover solution actually be, when you still have to manually launch the application.

Comment: Thank you. I can't do anything with GUI, the server is proprietary, closed sourced and I don't have any budget to contact vendors to rewrite it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried NLB (Network Load Balancing) from Microsoft? There you are able to configure two servers running same services and just make sure your clients are connecting to IP/name of NLB cluster and not to specific server... 
Sounds to me like you have failover cluster instead maybe?

Comment: Thanks. I have not tried NLB yet as I hope to find something simpler (may be some kind of user space tunneling solution, not monstrous NLB).

I can't use failover cluster as the service is a GUI application to which I need to have access to.

Comment: NLB is actually simple application with not really much of options. Just keep in mind, that balanced servers shall use static data only. If you need application to store some data, then data should be stored on some 3rd server, because next time you connect you might be routed to different NLB node that don't have your updated data, unless you will have some further live data sync implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a small self-made application, which opens socket connection to both hosts in parallel and then uses netsh interface portproxy to set up port forwarding to the host responded. Client connects to localhost using the port created by netsh command. I invoke the application every 30 seconds through task scheduler on client machine.